# getting color from 0-1 range in matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib

I have a number of scatterplots for which i would the color of the plot to represent correlation between the variables. Correlation is normalized to [0,1] and I would like something like blue for 0 to red for 1, but I'm ok with other combinations.

What is the code to convert my correlation figure to something matplotlib puts on a color spectrum?

```
for col_s in s_data.columns[1:3]:
    for col_e in economic_data.columns[1:3]:
        x= s_data[col_s].interpolate(method='nearest').tolist()
        y= economic_data[col_e].interpolate(method='nearest').tolist()

        corr=np.corrcoef(x,y)[0,1]
        plt.scatter(x, y, alpha=0.5, c=to_rgb(corr))
        plt.show()
```

Answer (score 3):

You can specify a color map and then define the colors simply as the correlations dependent on that color map. First, you need to import [cm](http://matplotlib.org/api/cm_api.html) from matplotlib:

```
import matplotlib.cm as cm
```

Then, change your code's plot line to:

```
plt.scatter(x, y, alpha=0.5, c=corr, cmap=cm.rainbow)
```

You are able to customize the color map with [any of matplotlib's color maps](http://matplotlib.org/examples/color/colormaps_reference.html).

Comment: Thanks but I get this error: "Cannot convert argument type <type 'numpy.ndarray'> to rgba array"

Comment: Okay, so that's because x and y are len > 1, while corr is a single value. Try c=str(corr) in the plot command and see if that works. Though, that will only help with a grayscale.

Comment: Yes. It runs, but in grayscale.

Answer (score 0):

You could map your parameter in `[0, 1]` to a hex value:

```
def corr2hex(n):
    ''' Maps a number in [0, 1] to a hex string '''
    if n == 1: return '#fffff'
    else: return '#' + hex(int(n * 16**6))[2:].zfill(6)

print corr2hex(0.31)

>>> 
#4f5c28
```

Then you can pass this to matplotlibs [`to_rgb()`](http://matplotlib.org/1.2.1/api/colors_api.html#matplotlib.colors.ColorConverter.to_rgb) to get back a RGB triple.